# Django Celery Result : Django-DB ttributeError: 'DisabledBackend'

Tags: django, django-celery

I'm currently testing Django Celery Results using Django DB as backend.

I've followed the documentation here: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#django-celery-results-using-the-django-orm-cache-as-a-result-backend

When my Django view calls the celery task, it gets properly added in the Django DB and the task gets executed by Celery worker. I can also fetch the task ID with below code:

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            res = mailer.delay(
                cd['subject'],
                cd['message'],
                cd.get('email', 'noreply@gmail.com'),
                ['seb.pouplin@gmail.com'])

            cel_taskid = res.task_id
            result = AsyncResult(cel_taskid)
            print(result.state)
            return HttpResponse(cel_taskid)
```

However, whenever I try to fetch task status, state or ready() flag, I'm getting following exception:

**AttributeError: 'DisabledBackend' object has no attribute '_get_task_meta_for'**

Is there any limitation using Django-DB to get the task details or any other way to retrieve them ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I was able to access the Celery task result using TaskResult model from django_celery_results .

Answer (score 1):

I was able to access the Celery task result using TaskResult model from django_celery_results.

Best solution is to add `(bind=True)` in the task decorator to access the task object attributes.